# String Compression loop logic

Tags: java, string, compression

My for loop for my string compression is a bit off. I have been working on this assignment the past 5 days and I can't figure out for the life of me what is wrong. Can someone help me out?

For example, I passed over the string `"TTTTrrrEe"` and instead of getting `T4r3Ee`, I'm getting `T4r3EeTT`. I don't know why it jumps back to the beginning of the string like that, but I am getting closer.We can only use `charAt`,`equals`,`length`, and `substring` from the string class.

Can someone help guide me in the right direction by helping to correct my logic? I still want to try and code this myself, seeing as how it is an assignment.

```
public static String compress(String s){
    int count = 0;
    String temp = s.substring(0,1);
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(i !=s.length()-1){
            if(temp.equals(s.substring(i,i+1))){
                count++;

            }else{

                if(count < 1){
                    System.out.print(s.substring(i,i+2));
                    System.out.print(temp.substring(0,1) );
                }else{
                    System.out.print("" + temp.substring(0,1) + count);
                    i--;
                    temp = s.substring(count,count+1);
                    System.out.println(" temp is now " + temp);

                    count = 0;
                    //i--;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    System.out.println(temp);

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you loop through the String and check the character by String.charAt(i) instead of subString(). It will make your life easy.

Comment: As general programming practice, try to avoid deep nesting. For example, `if(i != s.length() - 1){//loop body}`, try `if(i == s.length()-1){continue;}//loop body`

Comment: Is the assignment ignoring the fact that this is an ambiguous compression algorithm, unless your string cannot contain numbers?

Comment: There is no need to include java in the question title if you already included it as a tag.  Also the "help needed" in the question is unnecessary since it is obvious that you need help from the fact that you are posting a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a learning exercise, I wouldn't try fixing your code, just point out a few things to work on to get it right:

- The `if (i !=s.length()-1)` condition inside the loop becomes unnecessary if you change your `for` loop condition to `i < s.length()-1`
- Comparing individual characters is easier (and faster) than comparing substrings. You get a character at position `i` by calling `char ch1 = s.charAt(i)`, and compare two characters using `==` operator, rather than calling `equals()` on them.
- When `count` is zero (your `count < 1` condition is equivalent to `count == 0`) you print both the current character and the character after it, in addition to the first character of `temp` followed by the count. This does not look correct.
- Rather than growing `temp` as you go through the loop, you set it on each iteration. This does not look correct.
- A better way of growing `temp` as you go through the loop is using [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and `append()`, instead of using a plain `String`, and performing concatenations.

Comment: I would probably use an inner loop on the same variable as the outer loop. Then you can fix a character easily for the inner loop

Answer (score 0):

Try using some logic like this;

```
int count = 0;
for(int i =0; i < string.length()-1; i++){
    if(string.charAt(i) == string.charAt(i + 1)){
        count++;
        // DO SOME OPERATION
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I just planned to give the sketch, so that the OP could solve it using the logic. Did not want to give the entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

`temp = s.substring(count,count+1);` does not relate to a *position* (`i`), but a *size*.

In fact I would try to rewrite it afresh, with externally sensible names:

```
char repeatedChar = `\u0000`; // Not present.
int repetitions = 0;
```

Because of the no-namer `count` you got into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
public  class HelloWorld  {

public static void compress(String s){

    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();

    char tmp = '\0';

    int index = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){

        char curr = s.charAt(i);            

        if(buff.length() == 0){             
            tmp = curr;
            buff.append(tmp);
            continue;
        }           

        if(curr == tmp){
            index++;
        }
        else{                   
            if(index > 1){
                buff.append(index);
                index = 1;
                tmp = curr;
            }

            buff.append(curr);              
        }


    }

    System.out.println(buff.toString());

}


public static void main(String args[]){
    compress("TTTTrrrEe");
}
 }
```

Output:  `T4r3Ee`

For `compress("TTsssssssssssTTrrrEe");`

Output: `T2s11T2r3Ee`

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
    public class Compress {

        /**
         * @param args
         * @author Rakesh KR
         */
         public static String encode(String source) {
                StringBuffer dest = new StringBuffer();
                for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
                    int runLength = 1;
                    while (i+1 < source.length() && source.charAt(i) == source.charAt(i+1)) {
                        runLength++;
                        i++;
                    }
                    dest.append(source.charAt(i));
                    dest.append(runLength);
                }
                return dest.toString();
            }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String example = "aaaaaaBBBBccc";
            System.out.println("Encode::"+encode(example));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`String temp = s.substring(0,1);`

`temp.equals(s.substring(i,i+1))`

In case of these 2 sentences you should have used a `char` instead of String, as such:

`char temp = s.charAt(0)`

`temp == s.charAt(i)`

I would start with 3 variables:

`char lastCharacter = inputString.charAt(0);`
`int count = 1;`
`String result = "";`

then proceed to process the input string in a loop:

```
if (length <= 1) return inputString;
for i = 1 ; i < length;i++
    if (inputString.charAt(i) == lastCharacter && i != length-1)
        count++
    else
        if count == 1 
            result += lastCharacter
        else 
            result = result + lastCharacter + count;
            count = 1;
        end if
        lastCharacter = inputString.charAt(i);
    end if
end for
return result;
```